# How do I check if a user is banned or not?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have managed to make the unban command to work, but now I need to make a condition to avoid errors, and need to put the unban code inside the condition if the user is in the ban list, but I have no idea how and haven't seen anything on internet.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/111) might help

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Guild.fetchBans()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBans) to retrieve a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of banned users. Keep in mind, this method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You can then use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to search through the Collection.

Example:

```js
// Async context needed for 'await' (meaning this must be within an async function).
// Assuming 'message' is a Message within the guild.

try {
  const banList = await message.guild.fetchBans();

  const bannedUser = banList.find(user => user.id === 'someID');

  if (bannedUser) await message.channel.send(`${bannedUser.tag} is banned.`);
  else await message.channel.send('That user is not banned.');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me with my own issue I've been having. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An update due to Discord.js' package latest updates. The new method to make sure whether a user is banned or not is similar to the previous one, though you will now want to state:

```
const targetId = banList.get(guildmemberID).user
```

With "guildmemberID" being my constant, meaning you can replace it with anything you'd like, just as such:

```
const guildUser = args[0]
```

The "args[0]" variates according to what you are aiming to do. After putting everything together, your code could look similar to the following:

```
const guildmemberID = args[0]

try {
  const banList = await message.guild.fetchBans();
  const targetId = banList.get(guildmemberID).user

                      if(targetId) {
                        await message.guild.members.unban(targetId);
                        await message.channel.send('This user has been unbanned!');
                      } else {
                          await message.channel.send('This user is not banned')
                      }
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

Keep in mind that you are not able to use `try/catch` blocks if it's not within an async function.

I hope it helped!